# Using connection keepalive in grpc for blockingStubs

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

Want to enable connection keep alive option for the gRPC API calls. Current code makes use of blocking stubs (synchronous calls using java client). I would like to know if the connection keep alive options (described in the link below) are expected to work with he blocking stubs?

https://cs.mcgill.ca/~mxia3/2019/02/23/Using-gRPC-in-Production/

Desired behavior - Blocking API calls should fail in reasonable time if there is any issues with server (say server crashes or killed for some reason)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In grpc-java, the stubs are a thin layer on top of a more advanced API (ClientCall/ServerCall). The stub type does not impact the Channel-level features. The keepalive channel option will work independent of the stub type.

Keepalive will kill pending RPCs on a connection to a remote server that crashes/hangs/etc. It does not kill RPCs when the server just takes a long time to respond to the RPC.